# Remove NaNs from DataFrame and duplicates from multi-index

Tags: python, pandas

Given a multi-index DataFrame:

```
                 col_A  col_B
level_0 level_1              
A       x          1.0    NaN
        y          NaN    1.0
        x          NaN    2.0
        y          2.0    NaN
```

How can I remove the NaNs from the df and duplicates from the multi-index to get:

```
                 col_A  col_B
level_0 level_1              
A       x          1.0    2.0
        y          2.0    1.0
```

Here is the MWE:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A', 'A'],
                                  ['x', 'y']],
                                 names=['level_0',
                                        'level_1'])
data =[
    [1, np.NaN],
    [np.NaN, 1],
    [np.NaN,2],
    [2, np.NaN],
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index=index, columns=['col_A', 'col_B'])
print df
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `groupby` on `index` names, and take `first` values.

```
In [642]: df.groupby(level=df.index.names).first()
Out[642]:
                 col_A  col_B
level_0 level_1
A       x          1.0    2.0
        y          2.0    1.0
```

Note: Post edit, realized it's almost identical to Psidom's answer. A minor generic edit to `level`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sum` with `level` parameter:

```
df.sum(level=[0,1])
```

Or as @JohnGalt suggests:

```
df.sum(level=df.index.names)
```

Output:

```
                 col_A  col_B
level_0 level_1              
A       x          1.0    2.0
        y          2.0    1.0
```

Comment: Ah, this is smart, can be generic with `df.sum(level=df.index.names)`?

Comment: nice and succinct

Answer (score 2):

Try [`groupby.first`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.20.3/pandas/core/groupby.py#L1141-L1158) which takes the first non missing value:

```
df.groupby(level=[0,1]).first()

#                 col_A col_B
#level_0 level_1        
#      A       x    1.0   2.0
#              y    2.0   1.0
```

Comment: first do make it ~

Answer (score 1):

Or you can using `idxmax`

```
df.reset_index().groupby(['level_0','level_1']).idxmax()
```

or simply using

```
df.stack().unstack()

Out[242]: 
                 col_A  col_B
level_0 level_1              
A       x          1.0    2.0
        y          2.0    1.0
```